# Is Stack Overflow an appropriate site for asking about installing Inkscape for Cygwin?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I'd like to know how I could get the [Inkscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape) command line working in [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), but I'm not sure whether Stack Overflow or another Stack Exchange site would be the best place to ask this question.

Comment: In short: **No**, it isn't.

Comment: Uh, **no**. I'm unsure why you're asking this question. To see if your question would be on-topic look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ It was the right decision to post it here. That way the OP learns what is off topic or not. The attitude given to him isn't going to help him and would drive him away.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Inkscape is not a *software [tool] commonly used by programmers* as [mentioned in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so no, that would not be on-topic. Trying to get the command line to work in Cygwin doesn't involve programmatic use of the tool.

It would be better asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) instead. There are both [`cygwin`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cygwin) and [`inkscape`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/inkscape) tags to apply to your question there. [`command-line`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line) is probably also applicable.